# psql - Inserting entries into a table from another table

Tags: sql, sql-insert, postgresql-9.3

How to insert entries into table **foo** only the comm_id from table **waldo** while the other columns (managed, status, and type) are added in static values?

**TABLE foo**

```
     comm_id     |    managed    |    status    | type |
-----------------+---------------+--------------+------+
  COMM_11.21.6   |     true      |     NULL     | NULL |
  COMM_14.15.7   |     true      |     NULL     | NULL |
  COMM_13.03.9   |     true      |     NULL     | NULL |
```

**TABLE waldo**

```
     comm_id     |    address    |  stat_id  |
-----------------+---------------+-----------+
  COMM_10.10.6   |     12345     |     1     |
  COMM_14.15.7   |     78543     |     2     |
```

**Desired Output for TABLE foo**

```
     comm_id     |    managed    |    status    | type |
-----------------+---------------+--------------+------+
  COMM_11.21.6   |     true      |     NULL     | NULL |
  COMM_14.15.7   |     true      |     NULL     | NULL |
  COMM_13.03.9   |     true      |     NULL     | NULL |
  COMM_10.10.6   |     true      |     NULL     | NULL |
```

the values managed = true, status = NULL and type = NULL is static so I just want to add them by value. And **COMM_14.15.7** is not added to **foo** because the id already exists there.

```
INSERT INTO foo (comm_id, managed, status, type ) VALUES ('id from waldo', 'true', 'NULL', 'NULL' );
```

The query above inserts static values to the table.

```
INSERT INTO foo SELECT comm_id FROM waldo WHERE comm_id NOT IN (SELECT comm_id FROM foo);
```

Is there any way to manipulate or combine these queries so I can get all the **comm_id** from waldo into foo and put static values at the same time? Your suggestions and ideas are highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

is it

```
INSERT INTO foo (comm_id, managed, status, type ) 
select comm_id , true, NULL, NULL 
from waldo 
WHERE comm_id NOT IN (SELECT comm_id FROM foo);
```

note I omitted quotes around boolean true and nulls, which is only a guess not knowing the structure of foo

Comment: Yes. This exactly returns the output I desire. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
INSERT INTO foo (com_id,managed,status,type)
select comm_id,'true',NULL,NULL from
(
SELECT comm_id FROM waldo 
minus
SELECT comm_id FROM foo
);
```